# How would you best visualize data that fits into many categories?

Tags: data-visualization, many-categories

[image]
https://public.tableau.com/shared/T22HDMQ44?:display_count=yes

So I'm visualizing my Steam game play information and I have access to the tags and features of games along with prices and hours spent playing each game.

I originally wanted to easily see in a scatter plot the price x hours x genre(through tags)

My trouble is that each game has numerous tags for example Pay Day 2 has tags FPS, Co-op, Stealth and Team-Based just to name a few. Now when I look at this chart instead of easily making conclusions on what types of games I play more...etc, a rainbow barfed on my page.

Are there any better ways to clearly display the Tags/Categories? I've thought about grouping the tags into smaller categories but even if I minimized them into 7 groups many games would still fit into many groups. I also realize steam tags are not the cleanest or best ways to categorize games but that's what I've got to work with unless I learn how to use Steam API. I've tried to look at one tag at a time by clicking on them, however you can only compare it to the grey mass behind it.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, could you perhaps give an example? And could a Venn diagram be of any help?

Comment: You could have a look through [this site](http://deltarho.org/) which specializes in visualizing large and complex data.

Comment: Could you post an example dataset for people to work with?